# Defined or not defined?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, c-preprocessor

I have a C tool I am trying to convert into C++ (CLR)...

I have a typedef as such:

```
#include <enginin.h>
#include <global.h>

typedef struct selfenginin_t
{
    short   nriskcalcs;             /* array size.*/
    struct hooks_t
    {
        short   cause;
        short   prec;
        float   rawgain;
        float   adjgain;
        BOOLEAN estimate;
    } 
    hooks[MAXHOOKS];

    . . .
}
```

I am getting an error in VS on the `hooks[MAXHOOKS]` line... when I mouse over it, I get the following text:

```
#define MAXHOOKS 50
Error: identifier "MAXHOOKS" is undefined
```

... well, at the start of the message it seems to understand that `MAXHOOKS` is 50, but by the end it seems to not be so sure.  This is a mystifying message to me.  The `MAXHOOKS` declaration is in the `enginin.h` file.

Can someone shed some light on what the problem actually is (or might be?  I don't know if I need to provide more information).

Comment: Where you defined `MAXHOOKS`? Before or after `struct`.

Comment: @haccks it is defined in an include.  I'll update the text of the question.

Comment: What about BOOLEAN? It's just bool in c++.

Comment: @laser_wizard yeah I added a #define BOOLEAN bool (which at least at this point is not blowing up on me, but I may have to refactor that)

Comment: Try compiling the code. IntelliSense tends to bug heavily with C (and C++) macros. Don't ever trust it much before compile-time ;)

Comment: We may need to see enginin.h.  Do you have the #define inside a namespace?

Comment: Already answered, but what about a missing semi-colon`};` at the end?

Comment: Just remembered something. Is `enginin.h` added to the VS project? If it isn't, that's most probably the cause of the IntelliSense error. It gave me this crap several times (VS 2012 Express Desktop), failing to keep track of changes made to a file in a different editor. Try adding the file to the VS project.

Comment: Hmya, you are not looking at the first error message in the Error List window.  *Other* errors can cause a train of extra failures, especially so if preprocessor macros are not parsed correctly.  A big reason why the .NET compilers you are used to don't have one.  Use Build + Build and start from the top.

Comment: @HansPassant: good note, but, IIRC, IntelliSense shouldn't show this exact error in that case =)

Comment: @Mints97, Compiling the code does not seem to help.  The file is included in the project.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I truncated the end; it does have a semicolon.